# Assign a new public and static IP to a router behind my main router (on hold) - edited

Tags: support

@Ronmaupin @Zac67 Hi Gentleman, could you please check my post "Assign a new public and static IP to a router behind my main route" it's on hold, I edit the post to comply the rules of the group. I appreciate

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the question that you are asking of us:

> In IPv6 I know that IPv6 Tunnel Brokers exists and works well but is
>   there something for IPv4 ?

Unfortunately, product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic on almost all SE sites (except [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) and [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)).

In any case, you got an answer and accepted it. A tunnel broker is really just a VPN provider (IPv6 over IPv4), and there are many of those for IPv4 (IPv4 over IPv4), but we cannot recommend one.